# Cassandra Port Issue

Tags: unix, cassandra

I unzipped Cassandra 2.2.3 tar ball file that I downloaded and ran the cassandra start script by issuing /bin/cassandra -f command without making any changes to the cassandra.yaml file.

When I ran it I got the below exception

"localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 is in use by another process. Change listen_address:storage_port in cassandra.yaml to values that do not conflict with other services"

When I ran "lsof -Pnl +M -i4" command to see what port is being used by what process, I saw port 7000 being assigned to Java and I was not able to kill it as well.

Can you please let me know what is happening here and what I should do if I face the same issue again?

For now I have deleted the extraction and re-extracted the files and re-booted the terminal to take everything back to initial steps.

-Satheesh

Comment: happened to me with cassandra 3.5 as well. system reboot solved problem.

Answer (score 3):

To just let know, re-booting the system disassociated the java process from the node 7000. So the error is not appearing anymore.. Just in case if some one is facing the same issue.

Thanks
-Satheesh

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because the Cassandra service is already running. Close that instance to start it again.

use `ps -ef | grep -i cassandra` on mac to find and kill the process. This solved the issue for me.